# Access to filesystem on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

I want to try AppHarbor, but I have an application which stores uploaded files in certain place on a filesystem. Is it compatible with AppHarbor? Can I store files in the file system and access them later?

(what kind of path can I expect, like c:\blabla something or what?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store files on the local filesystem, but the application directory is wiped on each new deployment so it's not recommended to rely on for file storage.

Instead we recommend that you use a cloud storage service such as [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage) or similar. There are .NET libraries for both services.

We recently wrote a blog post about [uploading files directly to S3 and GCS from the browser](http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/01/10/asynchronous-browser-uploads-to-s3-and-gcs-using-cors-aspnet-mvc) that you might want to read.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a background worker, you need to 'Enable File System Write Access' in the settings of you application.

Then, you are permitted access to write to: `Path.GetTempPath()`

Sourced from this support question: http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/5868-create-directory-in-background-worker